# C++: Question on access specifier in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

Here's the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B {
    private:
        int a=1;
    protected:
        int b=2;
    public:
        int c=3;
};

class D : protected B { // clause 1
};

class D2 : public D { // clause 2
    void x() {
       c=2;
    }
};

int main() {
    D d;
    D2 d2;
    cout << d2.c; // clause 3 Error due to c being protected
    return 0;
}
```

Note:

1. Clause 1 would make c to be protected.
2. Clause 2 would make c (protected in clause 1) to be public again.
3. Why clause 3 failed?

Comment: *Clause 2 would make c (protected in clause 1) to be public again.* Why do you think that?

Comment: Your clause 2 statement is incorrect

Comment: ok. I got it. Clause 2 would retain protected field as protected. :O)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of inheritance you use does not affect the protection level of members in the parent class. It only changes the protection level of those members in the child class.

When you define `class D : protected B` it is equivalent to defining class D like this:

```cpp
class D
{
protected:
  int b=2;
  int c=3;
};
```

Then when you define `class D2 : public D` it is equivalent to defining class D2 like this:

```cpp
class D2
{
protected:
  int b=2;
  int c=3;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your notes are not entirely correct:

1. `private` inheritance makes `public`, `protected` and `private` members be `private` in the derived class
2. `protected` inheritances makes `public` and `protected` members be `protected` in the derived class, and `private` members stay `private`
3. `public` inheritance changes nothing to the derived members' access.

`c` is `protected` in `D` and still `protected` in `D2` because of the `public` inheritance. There is no way to cheat visibility. What you assume would break logic. Visibility only goes downwards, not up.